# HTML, CSS how to make width of element always to bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

I have the image fixed in the center of page and grey div around it. Margins for top, left and right are 15px but it must fill all to bottom of page. I have image to show you what I mean. My question is how to make div height all to bottom, depends on what screen resolution is? Image how it should look:

[image]

```css
#IMAGE {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* padding-bottom: 50%; */
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div class="center" id="IMAGE">
    <h3 id="videoTitle"><?php echo "$title"; ?></h3> 
    <img src="./img/img.png" alt="Image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the section of your code related to your problem? So we can help you on how to fix it.

Comment: @pictus as per request Can you please show your code? It´s hard to understand what you mean. My idea is setting the image height to 100%, but without code it is only a idea.

Comment: My own little comment.... Should the image extend if the screen becomes larger / shrink when it becomes smaller? eventually becoming a 0 value if too small?

Comment: delete comment and move into your question by using edit please.

Comment: No, image doesn't change. I put that image is around 60% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vm0e0qra/)

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding:15px;
}

#wrapper:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-9999px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#wrapper img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but now the div height is 9999px and it keeps scrolling down

Comment: That's why there is `overflow:hidden` property on upper container, in this case `body` tag

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Thank you very much that is what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are going to need to use JavaScript. You take the height of the whole page, and the height of where you want your div to start. It will come out to be something like this.

```
$('#yourDiv').height($(window).height() - $('#top').height());
```

I think this is what you are asking for.

Comment: I think you are correct in jumping directly to Javascript. (jQuery in this case)

Comment: I think you are not correct, though. Css is the only magic needed here.